# Sidebar height equal to main content height

Tags: html, css, height

I am editing a wordpress theme [here](http://ta65doctor.com/newwordpress/product/ta-65-90-capsules/). I have a problem with the sidebar height.

How can I make the right sidebar as tall as the the main content?

Thank you for your interests to help

Comment: Can you show us the code..

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution you could use the matchHeight jQuery Plugin: see http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/. Alternative, for newer browsers you could take a look to flexbox (see a tutorial here http://clearleft.com/thinks/270).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

I just found stupid css solution

main{
overflow:hidden;
}

.shop-sidebar {
padding-bottom: 5000px;
margin-bottom: -5000px;
}

Comment: Great, a simple CSS Solution is always the best way to solve such a problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css **display:flex;** property

here is complete guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I give very  a simple example here :

```
<style>

.main{
    display: flex;
}
.content{
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.sidebar{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

</style>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="content"> <h3>this content</h3></div>
        <div class="sidebar"><h3>This side bar</h3></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found so stupid solution, for so stupid problem

```
main{overflow:hidden;}
.shop-sidebar, .primary-sidebar {padding-bottom: 5000px;margin-bottom: -5000px;}
```